# How do I define RowVersion in a C# class when using SQL Server and Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created a SQL table and an EF Fluent mapping as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Application] (
    [ApplicationId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (50) Not NULL,
    [DataVersion] ROWVERSION,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Application] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ApplicationId] ASC)
);
```

My EF Fluent API looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Application>
    {
        public ApplicationConfiguration()
        {
            Property(a => a.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(35);

            Property(p => p.RowVersion).IsRowVersion();

        }
    }
```

My Class looks like this:

```
public class Application
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestAccount> TestAccounts { get; set; }
    xxxxxxx
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can define the RowVersion in my class?

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me - I'm using EF4:

```
public class Application
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestAccount> TestAccounts { get; set; }

    public virtual byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public class ApplicationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Application>
{
    public ApplicationConfiguration()
    {
        Property(a => a.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(35);

        Property(p => p.RowVersion).HasColumnName("DataVersion").IsRowVersion();
    }
}
```

PS: The datatype of my database colum is **timestamp** (I'm using SQL Server 2005)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's

```
public class Application
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestAccount> TestAccounts { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] DataVersion { get; set; }
}
```